# How to output parameters in a dictionary from a gridsearch into a series of key word arguments

Tags: python-3.x, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to optimize the hyperparameters for a machine learning task and have written a function for testing various models. I would like to be able to take the best parameters identified by the grid search and put them in a format such that I could pass them as key word arguments when I am ready to fit the model.

I have this:

```
def optimization(classifier):
    if classifier == LR:
         param_grid = {'class_weight': [None,'balanced'], 'solver': ['liblinear', 'sag']}
    if classifier == DT:
        param_grid = {'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'splitter': ['best', 'random'], 'class_weight': [None,'balanced']}
    if classifier == RF:
        param_grid = {'n_estimators': [10,20,30], 'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']}
    print(str(classifier))
    print('Number of tested models: %i' % np.prod([len(param_grid[element]) for element in param_grid]))
    search = GridSearchCV(classifier(), param_grid, cv=10)
    search.fit(X,y)
    print('Best parameters: %s' % search.best_params_)
    print('Best score: ' + str(search.best_score_))

optimization(LR) # with LR being a logistic regression model
```

and it outputs this:

```
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>
Number of tested models: 4
Best parameters: {'solver': 'sag', 'class_weight': None}
Best score: 0.801363055516
```

Ideally, I would like to get the best parameters identified in the output into something that looks like this:

```
solver=sag, class_weight=None
```

so that I could easily plug them into a function later. I am very new to Python, so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a long time ago, but you pretty much figured it out except the last part. You can unpack dictionaries and put them in as function parameters like so

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression(**search.best_params_)
```